# Why wouldn't display: flex; work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning HTML/CSS at Udacity. I am trying to get the first row items `col-2` and `col-10` to fall in the same row next to each other but the `display: flex;` wouldn't work. Any pointers please?

```css
*{
 border: red solid 1px; !important
}

*{
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*{
 text-align: center;
}


}
.row {
 width : 100%;
 display: flex;
}

.col-1 {
 width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
 width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
 width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
 width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
 width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
 width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
 width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
 width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
 width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
 width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
 width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
 <title>FRONT-END NINJA</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FroEndNja.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-2">Udacity Logo</div>
 <div class="col-10">JANE DOETTE<br>FRONT-END NINJA</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">IMAGE</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">FEATURED WORK</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-4">IMAGE1</div>
 <div class="col-4">IMAGE2</div>
 <div class="col-4">IMAGE3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-4">TEXT1</div>
 <div class="col-4">TEXT2</div>
 <div class="col-4">TEXT3</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Thank you,

Abhilash

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra closing brace in your CSS which was throwing an error

```
*{
    text-align: center;
}


} /* here */
.row {
    width : 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

```css
* {
  border: red solid 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}
.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}
.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}
.col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}
.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <title>FRONT-END NINJA</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FroEndNja.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">Udacity Logo</div>
    <div class="col-10">JANE DOETTE
      <br>FRONT-END NINJA</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">IMAGE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">FEATURED WORK</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">IMAGE1</div>
    <div class="col-4">IMAGE2</div>
    <div class="col-4">IMAGE3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">TEXT1</div>
    <div class="col-4">TEXT2</div>
    <div class="col-4">TEXT3</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) property, it should work if you set it to `row` ? Also, use autoprefixer if you use flexbox so that your stuff works across browsers.

Comment: flex-direction is by default set to row.